# How is "Received DPS" calculated?

Tags: battle-inf

I know that better armor (more defense) lowers the amount of damage I take. But my received DPS also seems to drop and spike at a somewhat random rate. I gather this has something to do with the number of people that are alive on the frontline, but how exactly is this damage calculated? Is the DPS split amongst everyone on the frontline or do we each get some amount of damage reduction based on how many people there are?